# Using a block object instead of a selector?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I have:

```
[self schedule:@selector(tickhealth)];
```

And tickHealth method only has one line of code:

```
-(void)tickHealth
{
    [hm decreaseBars:0.5];
}
```

is it possible to use block objects in place of a selector. for example something like:

```
[self schedule:^{
    [hm decreaseBars:0.5];
}];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Caleb & bbum correctly pointed out you cannot simply pass a block to your existing (and unchanged) `- (void)schedule:(SEL)selector;` method.

You can however do this:

Define block type:

```
typedef void(^ScheduleBlock)();
```

Change `schedule:` method to be defined similar to this:

```
- (void)schedule:(ScheduleBlock)block {
    //blocks get created on the stack, thus we need to declare ownership explicitly:
    ScheduleBlock myBlock = [[block copy] autorelease];
    //...
    myBlock();
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
[self schedule:^{
    [hm decreaseBars:0.5];
}];
```

---

Further Objective-C block goodness compiled by Mike Ash that will get you kickstarted with blocks:

- http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2008-12-26.html
- http://mikeash.com/pyblog//friday-qa-2009-08-14-practical-blocks.html
- http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-06-03-objective-c-blocks-vs-c0x-lambdas-fight.html

Comment: This method and the OP's method are incompatible; a SEL is not the same as a block.

Comment: @bbum: Right, that's why I had written "Define `schedule:` method similar to this:…". Should have written "re-define" for clarity, maybe. Corrected.

Answer (score 5):

You can't just pass a block in place of a selector because those two things have different types. However, if you have control over the `-schedule:` method, you can easily modify it to accept and use a block in place of a selector.